# how can I frozen, fixed label when scroll down on the jquery flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/7FfMd/3/

I have x-axis label at the top, when scroll down since the height of the chart is very height, I want to have the label still visible, or fixed, or frozen. How can I do that?

This use jquery and jquery flot.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some incarnation of this possibly.

http://jsfiddle.net/7FfMd/5/

**I would do this though:**

There is a navigation plugin that lets you pan and zoom.  I would just make sure your graph is within the bounds of the page (no scroll bars) and let people pan and zoom.

Plugin: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.navigate.js

Plugin Example: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/navigate.html

Comment: It does work for the purpose of scrolling down. Could you make it work for the horizontal scrolling too? That instant of the x-axis label is not moving at all when scroll to the right. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I want to implement